# RestKit - Deprecations and Semantic Issue Warnings in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, restkit

I'm getting 26 warnings due to Semantic Issue and Deprecations for RestKit, and I've looked through the Issues on her for the fix because I'd assume there is one, but I can't find it.

Can anyone post the link or help me out here? I'm newer to this, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Make sure you use the most current code base as pointed out on GitHub/RestKit

Comment: @Volker thanks for the response!  Just to check though, since I dragged the RestKit project file into my project (and didn't use CocoaPods), does that mean I need to do a total uninstall of the old version & then a total reinstall of the updated version?  Or is there an easier way?  Thanks so much!

Comment: You should follow the install guide (whether you use pods or not). Also, in this kind of question you should say what version of RestKit and Xcode you're using and the OS version you're targeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Wain's response, I followed the install guide to reinstall.